# $(ad)^2 - (bc)^2 + (ac)^2 - (bd)^2 = 2020$, find the values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are positive integers;

$a > b > c > d > 1$;

$$(ad)^2 - (bc)^2 + (ac)^2 - (bd)^2 = 2020$$

Is there a proper way to solve this question instead of just guessing random values for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Just use $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ to factor the expression into $3$ factors, then decompose $2020$ in prime factors.

Comment: Edited the question, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can show that it's equivalent to $(a-b) (a+b) \left(c^2+d^2\right)=2020$, then you can consider divisors of $2020$...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still a little bit confused.. I know 2020 = 2 * 2 * 5 * 101, but I have no idea what to do next

Comment: You have to choose among all divisors of $2020$ three divisors such that, when we multiplie them, we get $2020$. Example : 101,5  and 4 (they are lots of such triplets) and then you have to attribute them to $(a-b)$, $(a+b)$, $(c^2+d^2)$ and verify which such $a,b,c$ work

Comment: All right, thanks for the help!